# Sequence of Functionals

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

There are some statements in something that I'm reading that I don't quite understand:

> Consider $c=\sup c_n$ where $c_n$ is a non decreasing sequence of non-negative, uniformly continuous functions. Define the following functional: $$I_j[\pi] = \int c_j \, d\pi$$
>   Also consider a sequence of measures $(\pi_n)$ which admits a cluster point $\pi_*$.
>   Whenever $n \geq m$ we have $I_n[\pi_n] \geq I_m[\pi_n]$ (because $c_n \geq c_m$ for the same $\pi_n$). By continuity of $I_m$:
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n[\pi_n] \geq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_m[\pi_n] \geq I_m[\pi_*]$$
>   Further:
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}I_n[\pi_n] \geq \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}I_m[\pi_*]$$

So I'm trying to unpack the string of inequalities and the questions I have are:

1. Why is this true: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n[\pi_n] \geq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_m[\pi_n]$$
2. I suspect continuity of $I_m$ is used in the second part of the inequality on the first line:
   $$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_m[\pi_n] \geq I_m[\pi_*]$$
   I don't see how its used though.
3. On the second line:
   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}I_n[\pi_n] \geq \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}I_m[\pi_*]$$
   Does this follow from the first string of inequalities? In particular, we showed this statement was true for any particular $m$ on the first line. So we assert it must be true for any $m$ no matter how large?

Comment: Why don't you say what kind of objects $\pi$ and $\pi_n$ are?

Comment: I assume that the $\pi_n$'s are of course measures and the $I_n's$ act as functionals on your set of measures. Consider adding their definitions though. 

The statements in question read easier if the indices of the $\pi_j$'s are allowed to vary independently from the limits. Is that what the statement is saying?

Comment: @amsmath I didn't think it was important. They are joint distributions.

Comment: @rt6 Yes, the $\pi$'s are the measure and $I$ is the functional. I'll update this. Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: What do you mean by non-decreasing sequence? $c_n(x)\leq c_{n+1}(x)$?

Comment: @Icesea I mean pointwise on $X$. Basically there's a sup, and I'm asserting there's an increasing sequence of functions. I added the parenthetical, its not in the original problem statement. Maybe I goofed up something, how are you interpreting it?

Comment: So, what is the convergence of measure here ? convergent in the measure function space of convergent weakly star ?

Comment: It is easy to see that (by fixing $m$ first)
$$\lim I_n[\pi_n]=\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n[\pi_n] \geq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_m[\pi_n]$$
because any sequence $a_n\geq b_n$ implies $\limsup a_n\geq \limsup b_n$. Please tell me the topology for measure $\pi^*$. What do you mean by cluster point?

Comment: @Icesea the sequences of $\pi$ are weakly convergent: $I_n[\pi_n] \rightarrow I_n[\pi_*]$

Comment: Then we have $I_m[\pi_n]\to I_m[\pi^*]$

Comment: @Icesea I guess the thing that was confusing me about 1. $n$ is incrementing $c_n$ and $\pi_n$ on the LHS and only incrementing $\pi_n$ on the RHS. And in 2, he says he's using continuity -- but the conclusion seems to follow by weak convergence.

Comment: @Icesea here's what I'm looking at:
https://books.google.com/books?id=idyFAwAAQBAJ&q=By+monotone+convergence#v=snippet&q=So%2C%20by%20continuty&f=false

Comment: @yoshi Yeap, it is quite confusing.

Comment: @yoshi I see. It is only a cluster instead of "the limit"? I will update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67076/discussion-between-ice-sea-and-yoshi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that (by fixing $m$ first)
$$\lim I_n[\pi_n]=\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n[\pi_n] \geq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_m[\pi_n]$$
because any sequence $a_n\geq b_n$ implies $\limsup a_n\geq \limsup b_n$. Since 
$\pi_n$ is a sequence with a cluster $\pi^*$. We know that there exits a subsequence $\pi_{n_k}$ of $\pi_n$ such that $\pi_{n_k}\to \pi^* $ in weak$^*$ topology. 
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} I_m[\pi_n]\geq \lim_{k\to \infty} I_m[\pi_{n_k}]=I_m[\pi^*]
$$